# @ResponseBody @RequestBody- Object what happens exactly

Tags: java, xml, json, spring, rest

**EDIT**  I cleaned up my rather too long post. I will post the questions alone.

Please help to clarify my doubts. I will post code if required.

I tested Spring Rest controllers using spring rest template as a client with message converters, without message converters, with JSON jars in classpath and without JSON jars in classpath.

The behavior is different in each scenario which is what i wanted to clarify earlier.

My requirement is I need to send and get an XML as a String from client. In future we might neeed to be required to support objects.

I designed a simple controller with @RequestBody method with a JAXBObject as method argument which is set by message converters that convert XML string to  JAXB Object at server side.

//Controller

```
   @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/updatePricePlan" , consumes="application/xml" , produces = "application/xml")
   public @ResponseBody  ResponseEntity<Employee> updateEmployee( @RequestBody Employee emp ) {
  // code 
  }
```

I want to know:

1. will my approach support exchange of objects in future.
2. Can JAXB objects alone be used to send as part of @RequestBody
3. Will  JSON be the default format if json jars are in classpath of the client code calling a rest service even though I explicitly set application/xml in the headers.
4. How is an object exactly sent as part of @ResponseBody or @RequestBody.
5. If client expects and object instead of XML as string will message converters at server side not convert the JAXB object in above example to XML as string and return the object as is
6. If point 5 is true based on my understanding is the object passed as is to the client? Is it a good practice to send JAXB objects instead of POJO objects

Comment: Please be specific, this is too long question, nobody will bother to read your whole question.

Comment: I want to know exactly how object is sent over Http when using spring rest controllers. I tried different scenarios. Since the forum requires code and our current understanding. i gave the scenarios i tried and the questions i have for each. Can you please clarify my doubts

Comment: This is a novel. I see like 4-5 questions in there. Probably best to break it up into separate questions.

Comment: very tough even to glance through

Comment: I updated with questions alone. I apologize for my earlier long post I thought giving all the info will make it easy for others to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't know what you mean by the exchange of objects in the future.  If you mean you want to replace Employee with some other object then that will work fine but you will get different XML.  Unless `Employee` and `NewEmployee` (whatever you're replacing it with) have the same XML output, then that would be seamless.

   1. Again, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, if you're asking if JAXB is the only XML library that is allowed that is not the case.  JAX-RS supports `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter` providers being added.  You can use these to add alternate XML readers and writers.  If you're asking if you can use some other format (e.g. JSON with Jackson) then you can but you'd be best off writing a different method to do it.
   2. As the server you don't set the headers of the request unless you're intercepting and replacing the client's headers which would be very strange.  If the client makes a request with a JSON content type header then they would get an HTTP 415 error as you don't have any method that "consumes" the JSON content type.
   3. Clarified below
   4. I'm not sure what you mean.  Clients will get an XML string.  They will have no concept of an `Employee` object unless they've written such a class themselves.  They will also have to take care of deserializing the XML string into their `Employee` object.
   5. The client is given an XML string, not an object.  What is the difference between a JAXB object and a POJO object?

Here is what happens when you get a request.

1. The request arrives at the server.  At this point it is an HTTP request which is a big long string of headers and HTTP info plus a body which is just a stream of bytes.  I'm assuming the body is an XML string.
2. The request is passed to the JAX-RS servlet.
3. The JAX-RS servlet looks through its list of resources (`@Path`) to find all methods which match the URL, content-type header, and accept header.  There may be multiple matches for different content types.
4. The JAX-RS servlet looks through its list of `MessageBodyReaders` and `MessageBodyWriters` to see if it can find a `MessageBodyReader` which can convert a message with the given content type to the object type that is the `@RequestBody` (it checks with the [accept](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html#isReadable%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.reflect.Type,%20java.lang.annotation.Annotation%5B%5D,%20javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType%29) method) and a `MessageBodyWriter` that can convert the response object class to a message with the appropriate produces type.
5. If it finds a match then it executes that method using the `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter` to serialize/deserialize the objects.

For example, let's assume all you have is the method you posted above.

- If a request comes in with a content-type of application/json then JAX-RS will find matches that have the same URL but don't match the consumes annotation.  JAX-RS will return a 415.
- If a request comes in with a content-type of application/xml and an accept header of application/json then JAX-RS will find matches that have the same URL but don't match the produces annotation.  JAX-RS will return a 415.
- If a request comes in with a content-type of application/xml and an accept header of application/xml then JAX-RS will find that method as a match.  It will then look for a `MessageBodyReader` that can accept `("application/xml", Employee.class)`.  The default JAXB `MessageBodyReader` accepts `("application/xml", <any class with @XmlRootElement>)` and so it will match this.  JAX-RS will then look for a `MessageBodyWriter` that can accept `("application/xml", Employee.class)`.  The default JAXB `MessageBodyWriter` accepts `("application/xml", <any class with @XmlRootElement>)` and so it will match this.
- JAX-RS will then pass the request body as an `InputStream` to the default JAXB `MessageBodyReader` which will deserialize the request into an `Employee` object.
- JAX-RS will call your method with the `Employee` object and take the response.
- JAX-RS will then pass the response to the default JAXB `MessageBodyWriter` along with an `OutputStream` to represent the response body.  The `MessageBodyWriter` will serialize the `Employee` object into an XML string.
- This XML string will be encapsulated into an HTTP response with a Content-Type of "application/xml" and sent back to the client.